# How to correctly place number with mixed Arabic and English string

Tags: javascript, arabic

I'm working on a JavaScript code that displays a string with mixed Arabic, number and English words. The code replaces the substring "##" with one number, as follows,

```
" بون شاسع ##mi".replace("##",123)
```

I wish the result is (the number "123" is exactly before "mi" and after the Arabic character ) :

بون شاسع[image]

However, I always get the following result (the number "123" is unexpectedly placed before Arabic character ),
[image]

So, can anyone show me how to get this desired result?

Comment: Try adding `\u200E` right before the `##` (you can do it as part of the replacement). The left-to-right marker should help fix the issue.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol, could you tell why adding \u200E right before the ## can solve the problem? thanks.

Comment: `\u200E` is the Left-to-Right Marker character. It is an invisible character that tells the text renderer that what follows should be rendered in that direction - right now, it's putting the numbers as per the right-to-left direction that Arabic text uses.

Answer (score 2):

Since the text is Arabic, it uses the right-to-left direction. However, things can get tricky when you mix that with the number, which you want to appear left-to-right.

This can be fixed using `\u200E`, which represents the Left-to-Right Marker character. It is an invisible character that indicates to the text renderer that what follows should be rendered in that direction, regardless of what normal rules would suggest.

You can add the marker in as part of the `.replace` call, like so:

```
"بون شاسع##mi".replace("##","\u200E"+123)
```

Here's a comparison of the console output, without and with the marker:

[image: Console test]

Comment: if \u200E is added before the first ##, I can get the desired result. However, If  \u200E is added before the second ##, "123" will be the first characters of  line. Do you know the reasons?

Comment: The first "##" is before "mi". The second "##" is after "replace(".

Comment: It fails if the number exists in the string and we append that. is there a solution for this?